# gvNIX Typical security: advice how to add salt to password

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

I'm using Spring Roo with gvNIX Typical security (Spring security).  This works great! Thank you for the makers!

What is the best way to add salt to the password hashes with Typical security?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder` as suggest [Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-password-encoding):

> Always use a one-way password hashing algorithm such as bcrypt which uses a built-in salt value which is different for each stored password

To do that follow this steps:

1. modify `applicationContext-security.xml` file to change the `messageDigestPasswordEncoder` definition like this:

   ```
   <beans:bean 
       class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" 
       id="messageDigestPasswordEncoder"/>
   ```
2. Modify all references of `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` in code by `BCryptPasswordEncoder`
3. Replace any string-compare password validation by `BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches` method. Example in `UserController.create`:

   ```
   // Replace
   //
   // if(!savedUser.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())){
   //
   // by
   if(!messageDigestPasswordEncoder.matches(
            user.getPassword(), savedUser.getPassword())){
   ```
4. Use `messageDigestPasswordEncoder.encode` to store passwords on DB.

This is not tested but should work.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are a hero!

One small addition

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"
    id="bCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
</beans:bean>
```

Instead of the original

```
<beans:constructor-arg value="sha-256"/>
```

Would it be an idea to add this standard to the Typical Security plug-in?

Comment: Yes, feel free to add your improvement suggestion to https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO.